# Why would a cURL request from my website be refused by my own REST server that allows access?

Tags: rest, curl

I am trying to make a cURL REST request from my (UK2.net) Website to my home server.

```
curl -v https://ip:port/gethelloworld
```

This fails immediately, with the output (7) Connection refused. 
Trying the same curl request from my laptop I'm able to connect. 
I am also able to connect from other remote servers using a web browser; or an exe in Windows. I have also successfully made the curl request in an Ubuntu server.

I figure one of two things is happening:

*A) My Website has some configuration blocking it's access to my IP.

*B) My home server is blocking access to my websites IP.*

I'm reasonably sure my home server is not blocking it, I can't think which layer of software would have a specific rule against my web-host. 
I'm roughly sure it's not the protocol, I have tried using curl on multiple devices.
I have contacted the website hosts to check if they blocked my IP. That's not the problem.

Why would my site not want to get my wonderful "hello world" string from my server over cURL? And how would I test those reasons?

Comment: Where are you hosting your website? Is your home server ip address public? Do you have a NAT? Do you see where I'm going with all these questions?

Comment: Edited the post to include the webhost name. It is public, I have covered the fact that it does work. Unsure about NAT. No I don't know where you are going.

Comment: what about `tracert -h 255 ip`  ?

Comment: That won't work. Firewalls will block any other request.